# How should I implement an adaptive Metropolis algorithm for a Gibbs sampler with two Metropolis steps?

Tags: bayesian, metropolis-hastings

Consider the Gibbs sampler

1. Sample $\theta' \sim p(\theta|\tau, D)$
2. Sample $\tau' \sim p(\tau|\theta', D)$

Both conditional distributions are sampled with a Metropolis step. The joint distribution is unknown so that only a Gibbs sampler with two separate Metropolis steps can be used.

There are many forms of adaptive Metropolis algorithms which change the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ of the proposal (jump-) distribution assumed to be MV-normal and centered at the current values: $N(x|x',\Sigma)$. For example, in this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310243/which-adaptive-metropolis-hastings-algorithm-is-implemented-in-r-package-mhadapt) I wrote down the adaptive MH algroithm of Haario et al (1999). In an extension Haario et al. (2001) suggested to evaluate the empirical covariance matrix $S$ over the first $t_0$ MCMC draws and scaled by a factor $s=2.4^2/d$ as proposal variance $\Sigma$ (with d the dimension). A similar strategy is suggested by Gelman et al in 'Bayesian Data Analysis'(3rd ed., p. 296).

Now, when there is only one posterior to sample from, the approach is clear. However what should one do in the case of the two MH steps within Gibbs? We then have two proposals $\Sigma_{\theta}$ and $\Sigma_{\tau}$. Should we run the approach above two times, i.e. after $t_0$ draws calculate $S_{\theta}$ and $S_{\tau}$ across the draws of $\theta$ and $\theta$ respectively? Are there any results on this?

Comment: I'd reckon that just as Metropolis-within-Gibbs leads to multiple Metropolis-Hastings algorithms implemented in serial because you can't exploit the conditional dependence, you'd want to optimize the individual proposal distributions if you work under similar circumstances.

Comment: @Forgottenscience Yes I thought so too until I implemented it for my specific problem and it did not work. There may be other reasons why it does not work but I am wondering if there is an authoritative reference that supports this procedure. Most adapted MH algorithms are only discussed in terms of single target distributions.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have a look around. I've said this on here before, but check the new paper by Titsias and Dellaportas on adapative MCMC - I think its leagues better and much more promising compared to the ol' Haario method.

Comment: @Forgottenscience Thanks. Perhaps I will put a bounty on this one.

Comment: Could I ask you to explain how you know the conditional distributions, but not the joint distribution? It would also be useful to say which dimensions $(\theta, \tau)$ are.

Comment: @πr8 My specific application is complex but suffice to say that if $\theta|\tau$ is for example normal, and $\tau|\theta$ is for example log-logistic, or t, etc., then the joint distribution does not have standard form. Of course it may be possible to somehow derive their joint distribution using copulas but that I could not do yet. Is this sufficient explanation? The dimensions it round about 3-10.

Comment: I think even if it doesn't have a standard form, but the joint density can be written down,  then you can use a more standard MCMC scheme - I'm just curious as to whether there's a specific reason for preferring a Gibbs-type approach.

Comment: In principle, the optimal scale for the conditional π(θ|τ,D) is depending on the conditioning variate τ. However, once the joint posterior covariance matrix can be estimated, the rescaled conditional variances can be used in the Metropolis proposal.

Comment: Note that when the full conditionals are available, the joint is as well, thanks to the Hammersley-Clifford theorem:$$\pi(\theta,\tau|D)\propto\dfrac{\pi(\theta|\tau_0,D)\pi(\tau|\theta,D)}{\pi(\theta_0|\tau_0,D)\pi(\tau_0|\theta,D)}$$

Comment: @Xián very useful remark. I think this might help to reduce it back to a one-step MH algorithm. I do not yet understand the first remark. What do you mean by rescaled conditional variances? Do you perhaps have a reference?

Comment: I simply mean that the joint covariance matrix provides a conditional variance for each term, which should then be rescaled by 2.4.

Comment: @Xi'an Wait a moment... so we have $\Sigma$ the covariance matrix of the jumping distribution, as given in the question. $S$ is the estimate of the covariance of the posterior from all draws hitherto for the joint posterior distribution of $\theta,\tau$. Then we update $\Sigma := S * 2.4^2/d$ where $d$ is the number of parameters. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @tomka yes indeed. Since the Metropolis+Gibbs sampler converges, it consistently estimates the target covariance.

Comment: @Xi'an OK so for some reason this is not working. I rewrote the algorithm to sample jointly from $\theta, \tau | X, S, D$ with one MH using advice given above. Now $X,S$ are two latent variables parameterized by $\theta$ and $\tau$ respectively which are augmented as part of the Gibbs sampler. I omitted this information in the question as to not to overcomplicate things. The problem is that when I update $\Sigma$ the acceptance rate becomes small and may lead to degenrate posteriors. When I keep $\Sigma$ at fixed value, once tuned manually in advance, the algorithm works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to adapt less and less often for the procedure to be valid.

Comment: @Xi'an Is there anything to say about the relative advantage so sample with one MH step as opposed to iteratively with two separate ones?